# Azure BICEP Azure function resource eventgrid failing deployment

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-eventgrid

Getting below error while deploying:

```
ERROR: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/subscription/resourceGroups/rg-dev-policy-monitor/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/evtgrid-56","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ParentResourceNotFound","message":"Failed to perform 'write' on resource(s) of type 'systemTopics/eventSubscriptions', because the parent resource '/subscriptions/subscrition/resourceGroups/rg-dev-policy-monitor/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/devpolicyinsightstopic' could not be found."}]}}
```

```
bicep code:
param eventGridSubName string = 'dev-eventgrid-sub'
param topicName string = 'devpolicyinsightstopic'
param functionAppResourceId string = '${resourceGroup().id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/FN-PolicyMonitor'

resource evtTopic 'Microsoft.EventGrid/topics@2023-06-01-preview' = {
  name: topicName
  location: 'australiaeast'
  properties: {
    source: subscription().id
    topicType: 'Microsoft.PolicyInsights.PolicyStates'
  }
}

resource evtGridSub 'Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/eventSubscriptions@2023-06-01-preview' = {
  name: concat(evtTopic.name, '/', eventGridSubName)
  
  properties: {
    eventDeliverySchema: 'EventGridSchema'
    destination: {
      endpointType: 'AzureFunction'
      properties: {
        resourceId: functionAppResourceId
        maxEventsPerBatch: 1
                preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes: 64
      }
    }
    filter: {
      subjectBeginsWith: ''
      subjectEndsWith: ''
      includedEventTypes: [
        'Microsoft.PolicyInsights.PolicyStateChanged'
        'Microsoft.PolicyInsights.PolicyStateCreated'
        'Microsoft.PolicyInsights.PolicyStateDeleted'
      ]
    enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays: true
    }
  }
}

output evtGridSub.id string = evtGridSub.id
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: ParentResourceNotFound:

The issue occurs if a dependency resource is required for the deployment to take place. If it is an explicit dependency, add the `dependsOn:[]` block; otherwise, add the parent property with the syntax `parent:resourcesymbolicname`.

Modify your code as below:

```bash
resource evtGridSub 'Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/eventSubscriptions@2023-06-01-preview' = {
  name: 'topic/sub'
  parent: evtTopic
  
  properties: {
    eventDeliverySchema: 'EventGridSchema'
    destination: {
      endpointType: 'AzureFunction'
      properties: {
        resourceId: functionAppResourceId
        maxEventsPerBatch: 1
                preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes: 64
      }
    }
    filter: {
      subjectBeginsWith: ''
      subjectEndsWith: ''
      includedEventTypes: [
        'Microsoft.PolicyInsights.PolicyStateChanged'
        'Microsoft.PolicyInsights.PolicyStateCreated'
        'Microsoft.PolicyInsights.PolicyStateDeleted'
      ]
    enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays: true
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add `dependsOn` as shown.

```bash
dependsOn:[
evtTopic
]
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Refer this [doc](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/azure-bicep-deploy-an-event-grid-custom-topic-and-an-event-hub-handler) for sample template structure.